# What's the purpose of a key hash when you have the fingerprint?

Tags: gnupg, pgp

Looking for "Barack Obama" in Ubuntu's keyserver return [these results](https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?search=barack%20obama&fingerprint=on&hash=on&op=index)

For example, take the first search result:

```
pub rsa2048/86678817fca9987e2d9a3d3ea2437f33d4266cc0 2017-07-08T04:17:08Z
     Hash=40135e3a9da88180a317be949b301708
```

The first line is the key's fingerprint.

I can obtain the fingerprint of my keys using `gpg --list-keys --fingerprint`

1. What is the second line? Why we need a hash if we already have the fingerprint?
2. How can I retrieve the hash for my keys in gpg?
3. If my friend calls me to verify that the public key is mine, should I give him the fingerprint or the hash?

Comment: Please note that tags make more sense when they directly relate to the question, so less is more here.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're mistaken. The top hexidecimal value is the key ID. That's what they're explaining at the top of the search results page with: `Type bits/keyID            cr. time   exp time   key expir`.
The second line with "Hash=" is the fingerprint of the public key [calculated with MD5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_fingerprint#Security_of_public_key_fingerprints).

Fingerprints and hashes are functionally similar in that they are both produced by one-way functions. They both take arbitrarily large inputs and produce a smaller output. The important distinction is that cryptographic hash functions require [collision resistence](https://link.springer.com/referenceworkentry/10.1007%2F0-387-23483-7_69) while fingerprints do not. The trade-off is that hashes are slower than fingerprints to calculate. So for large amounts of data, use fingerprints. For security-critical applications, hashes. Or both, starting with the faster fingerprint and using it like a [Bloom filter](https://llimllib.github.io/bloomfilter-tutorial/). This specific case is a little confusing because MD5 *is* a cryptographic hash function used for fingerprints. MD5 is no longer considered trustworthy for cryptographic applications but can still function for fingerprints.

If you want the SHA256 hash you can use `ssh-keygen -i -e "SHA256" -f yourkeyfile`.

If you and your friend are using out-of-band communications to verify your keys then good job. Just use the fingerprint provided by `gpg --fingerprint`.